# Why setTableHeader() method throws NullPointerException?

Tags: java, swing, nullpointerexception, jtable, jtableheader

I try to add tooltips to my JTable header. In this case I use TTHeader class which extends JTableHeader Java class. Everything it seems to be fine, but when I try to add new TTHeader header to my JTable, than I get NullPointerException with Unknown Source. I don't know why. TTHeader class seems to be ok. Problem is somewhere else.

Here is code with my approach.
For JTable populate:

```
 private JPanel contentPane;
 private JScrollPane scrollPane;
 private JTable table;
 private String tooltipsSDB[] = {"SessionID", "UserID", "PatientID", "PluginID", "Date", "Time"};

 Connection conn = null;
 ResultSet rs = null;
 PreparedStatement ps = null;

 Table() {
      // Connection Component
      conn = ConnectionJDBC.ConnectDB();

      setTitle("My sample table");
      setSize(new Dimension(400, 400));
      setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
      setLocationRelativeTo(null);
      setVisible(true);

      contentPane = new JPanel();
      contentPane.setLayout(new BorderLayout(0, 0));
      setContentPane(contentPane);

      scrollPane = new JScrollPane();
      contentPane.add(scrollPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);

      table = new JTable() {
           public boolean isCellEditable(int row, int column) {
                return false;
           };
      };
      table.setAutoCreateRowSorter(true);
      // Populate JTable with data from SQL DB
      populateTable();
      scrollPane.setViewportView(table);
 }

 public void populateTable() {
      String sql = "SELECT * FROM " + ExampleDatabase + " ORDER BY " + ExampleData + " DESC";
      try {
           // Make Connection With DB
           ps = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
           rs = ps.executeQuery();
           ResultSetMetaData rsmetadata = rs.getMetaData();

           // Populate JTable
           int columns = rsmetadata.getColumnCount();
           DefaultTableModel dtm = new DefaultTableModel();
           Vector columns_name = new Vector();
           Vector data_rows = new Vector();
           for (int i = 1; i <= columns; i++) {
                columns_name.addElement(rsmetadata.getColumnName(i));
           }
           dtm.setColumnIdentifiers(columns_name);
           while (rs.next()) {
                data_rows = new Vector();
                for (int j = 1; j <= columns; j++) {
                     data_rows.addElement(rs.getString(j));
                }
                dtm.addRow(data_rows);
           }
           table.setModel(dtm);

           // Create Header For JTable
           TTHeader tth = new TTHeader(table.getColumnModel());
           tth.setToolTipStrings(tooltipsSDB);
           table.setTableHeader(tth); // On This Line I Get NullPointerException With Uknown Source

           table.repaint();
      } catch (SQLException e) {
           JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Populate table error! \n" + e);

      } 
 }

 public static void main(String args[]) {
      EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
           public void run() {
                try {
                     new Table();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                     JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
                }
           }
      });
 }
```

And TTHeader class:

```
String[] toolTips;

public TTHeader(TableColumnModel model) {
    super(model);
}

public String getToolTipText(MouseEvent e) {
    int col = columnAtPoint(e.getPoint());
    int modelCol = getTable().convertColumnIndexToModel(col);
    String retStr;
    try {
        retStr = toolTips[modelCol];
    } catch (NullPointerException ex) {
        retStr = "";
    } catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException ex) {
        retStr = "";
    }
    if (retStr.length() < 1) {
        retStr = super.getToolTipText(e);
    }
    return retStr;
}

public void setToolTipStrings(String[] toolTips) {
    this.toolTips = toolTips;
}
```

NPE appears when I choose second database from JComboBox. In JComboBox listener I call populateTable() method. Here is a more specific stacktrace:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
at mypackage.TTHeader.getToolTipText(TTHeader.java:19)
at javax.swing.ToolTipManager$insideTimerAction.actionPerformed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.Timer.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.Timer$DoPostEvent.run(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Line nr 19:

```
int modelCol = getTable().convertColumnIndexToModel(col);
```

Comment: First add `e.printStackTrace()` into your `catch` blocks to get the `exception` details then add to your post and point us to that line.

Comment: I'm almost convinced that's not where you get the NPE.

Comment: You are using a custom LAF. What happens when you use the default (Metal) LAF?

Comment: The problem appear when I select desired database from JComboBox. App throws NPE after selection made. At the start, when I launch application JTable is launched properly and tooltips works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you get an NPE and identified the line, the first thing you check is all occurrences of the dereferencing operator (`.`). The value on the left hand side(!) of such an operator will be `null`. (If you have multiple `.`s on one line, then one of those. So if your line is `foo.getBar().doSomething()`, either `foo` is `null` or `foo.getBar()` returns `null`. But what `doSomething()` returns does NOT matter.)

In this case, it will probably be the `getTable()` method that returns `null`.

Since Java 5 there have been two new, rather more sneaky possible
causes of NPE:

1. Implicit dereferencing in `for (Foo foo : fooCollection)`, here you get an NPE if `fooCollection` is null.
2. Auto-unboxing of numbers: `Integer i = null; int j = i + 1; //NPE here`

That's all you need to know about the debugging of NPEs in general, there's of course the even more general advice that you should either log variable values or use a debugger to execute your code step-by-step.

Comment: And that was the case. I moved initialization of JTable to method populateTable() and whenever user select desired DB than JTable is initialize from the begining. But I don't understand one thing - why I get NPE at the begining? I used getTable() for already initialized table so it shouldn't came up...

Comment: We should see more of your code to give you a precise answer but bear in mind that Swing applications are typically multi-threaded, so what is non-null for one thread can easily by null for another if you're not careful.

Comment: this is worst example of what exists, I have an issue with JTable populated from JDBC, isn't it